# Running a query in overpass-turbo

Tags: overpass-api, query-layer

I am trying to write a query that shows all the highway in an area, except for one feature in overpass-turbo. The query wizard in overpass-turbo has `highway=*` which shows everything. But I want to select everything except one.
For example: all `highway` except `residential` roads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could ask the wizard for:

```
(highway!=footway) and type:way
```

But this will return everything that has no defined value for highway at all, such as walls, streams, electrical lines and countless other things.

So what you *probably* want is to ask the wizard for:

```
(highway=*) and (highway!=residential) and type:way
```

This will return ways (lines, but no points or polygons) with a value for `highway` that is *defined* and anything but `residential`. OpenStreetMap has a fairly loose definition of highway, and you may get results like:

- `highway = raceway`
- `highway = steps`
- `highway = cycleway`
- `highway = corridor`

Always consult the [OpenStreetMap wiki for highway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway) (or whichever element you intend to use) before downloading it in this way.

I make some use of OpenStreetMap data downloaded through Overpass, and after a lot of messing with the query syntax, I gave up. Instead, I defined a short and very permissive query, and downloaded that. It contained a lot of elements I didn't want, so I wrote a Python script that filtered them out. This allowed me to keep count of high many elements I was discarding and how many I was keeping. But Overpass Turbo is an excellent place to get started.